# Replace SQLite with Postgres in MindsDB

Tags: postgresql, mindsdb

In the MindsDB configuration file, there is a `permanent_storage` location where mindsdb stores some data. Mindsdb documentation specifies that alongside local dir storage it saves some metadata inside the SQLite database. Is there a way to change the sqlite db with another option in our use case prefered would be postgresql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the default storage option and use different database by adding the new connection string using `MINDSDB_DB_CON` variable.
An example would be

```
MINDSDB_DB_CON='postgresql://user:secret@localhost'
```